# Best way to require exactly one of a set of keyword arguments in Python?

Tags: python

I'm writing a wrapper around a REST API, and I want to allow the user to retrieve a widget either by its name or by its database id.

So I made both keyword arguments. Now, it seems like you should only be able to pass in exactly one of them. That's not too bad to implement, though I'm not sure if it could be more readable.

```
def get_widget(id=None, name=None):
    if (id and name) or not (id or name):
        raise ValueError("Exactly one of (id, name) is required.")
    # do stuff
```

I'm curious: what should I do if I had `n` of these keyword arguments? I could take in `**kwargs` and enforce `len(kwargs) == 1`, but then I would need to iterate over kwargs in order to get the key, and then switch on the key.

Is there a better or more readable way?

Comment: Aside: Why not `def get_widget(id_or_name,what_has_been_sent):`? They'll have to send one of them anyway.

Comment: Make them all separate functions.

Comment: @BhargavRao: Mmm, seems like a good option, especially since I don't do anything different with the argument depending on which it is. Thanks! Still curious about the general case.

Comment: can you please show an example with several pairs of arguments? BTW, those are all arguments with a default value. They become keyword args if their name is specified when the function is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, I'd just take this approach:

```
def get_widget_by_id(id): pass  # your code here


def get_widget_by_name(name): pass  # your code here
```

In general, though, I'm not aware of any way to just allow one of two arguments without rolling your own check and exception. I think the cleanest way to write that would look something like this:

```
def get_widget(*, arg_one=None, arg_two=None):  # use the * to force keyword args

    if arg_one is None and arg_two is None:
        raise ValueError("No args provided."
                         " Must provide either 'arg_one' or 'arg_two'")
    elif arg_one is not None and arg_two is not None:
        raise ValueError("Too many args provided."
                         " Must provide only 'arg_one' or 'arg_two'")
    else:
        # do your thing
```

If you have a large number of arguments, you could use `any`/`all`

```
if all(_ is None for _ in (arg_one, arg_two)):
    pass
elif all(_ is not None for _ in (arg_one, arg_two)):
    pass
```

As yet another alternative, you could always just allow both `id` and `name`, redundant though it may be, and only return the widget if it matche *both*.

Answer (score 1):

The "common" case is to write multiple functions (`get_widget_by_id`, `get_widget_by_name`, etc.), and then redirect them to an internal `_get_widget` function so the code can be properly shared.

You could also make a `union`-type object using a class, but this might be more work, and potentially look strange to callers:

```
class WidgetKey(object):
  def __init__ (self):
    self._id = None
    self._name = None

  @property
  def id (self):
    return self._id

  @id.setter
  def id (self, val):
    self._id = val
    self._name = None

  @property
  def name (self):
    return self._name

  @name.setter
  def name (self, val):
    self._name = val
    self._id = None
```

E.g. just reset all other values when someone sets any one.  This is a little obtuse (and could be written cleaner), but if you have a huge set of arguments, this is sometimes useful.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way I've handled it:

```
def foo(a=None, b=None, c=None, d=None):
    if sum(x is not None for x in (a, b, c, d)) != 1:
        raise ValueError("Must supply exactly one of 'a', 'b', 'c', or 'd'")
```